# AngularJS Responsive Navigtaion Menu is Hiding Content in ng-view

Tags: angularjs

Here is my main view in index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header ng-controller="NavController" >
            <nav id="topNavBar" class="topNav" ng-class="{'responsive' : toggle}">
                <a href="#/" ng-click="toggle = false" ng-class="{active: isActive('')}">Home</a>
                <a href="#/about" ng-click="toggle = false" ng-class="{active: isActive('about')}">About</a>
                <a href="#/gallery" ng-click="toggle = false" ng-class="{active: isActive('gallery')}">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#/contact" ng-click="toggle = false" ng-class="{active: isActive('contact')}">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" id="menuIcon" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS for the navigation menu:

```
.topNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topNav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topNav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topNav #menuIcon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topNav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topNav a#menuIcon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topNav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topNav.responsive #menuIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topNav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

And here is app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })

  .when('/gallery', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/gallery.html',
    controller  : 'GalleryController'
  })

  .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
    controller  : 'ContactController'
  })

  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

app.controller('NavController', function($scope, $location) { 
    $scope.isActive = function(page) {
        return $location.path().substring(1) == page;
    }

    $scope.toggle = false;
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
    // Code for HomeController
});

app.controller('AboutController', function($scope) {
  // Code for AboutController
});

app.controller('GalleryController', function($scope, $http) {
    // Code for GalleryController
});

app.controller('ContactController', function($scope) {
    // Code for ContactController
});
```

When the screen size is less than 600px wide, my navigation menu collapses and displays a menu button. I had some working jQuery that triggered the drop-down menu when the menu button was clicked:

```
$("#menuIcon").on('click', function() {
    $("#topNavBar").toggleClass('responsive');
});
```

My Angular version behaves as follows:

1. When you click the menu button, the drop-down menu appears (good), but all the content in ng-view disappears (bad)
2. When you click the menu button a second time, the drop-down menu collapses (good)
3. When you perform #1 and then click a link in the menu, the appropriate page loads correctly and the drop-down menu collapses (good)

How do I fix this?

UPDATE: Solved

1. Switched from AngularJS 1.4 to latest version 1.7.5 (not sure why I was using 1.4....)
2. Updated navigation links to be href="#!/..." instead of href="#/..."
3. Removed href="#" from drop-down menu button (this was probably the root cause of my problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this helped me fix it!

I copied my markup from https://github.com/googlearchive/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/index.html, with the nav bar dropdown copied from a bootstrap example I found somewhere:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            {{ user.name }}<b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="" ng-click="changePassword()">Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      ...
    </div>
```

The problem is that when the user clicked the dropdown, it registered as a click on the `<a>` element and changed the URL to `/#`, which changed the content appearing in the main content block.

Removing `href="#"` from `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">` fixed the problem for me, so now the URL doesn't change (and thus the main content doesn't disappear from the `<div ng-view>` block) when the user clicks the dropdown!

```
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```